# How to root LAVA IRIS 504q?

Tags: rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean

I am having iris 504q model.My current android version is 4.2.2,but i am unable to update it any further,can any one guide me,how to root lava iris 504 q?

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the steps:-**

1. Make sure USB debugging is enabled. Go to **Settings > Developer Options > Enable USB Debugging**.
2. Download AND Install [MTK Drivers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2107980&d=1373524210) *(extract, right-click android_winusb.inf and select **install**)*
3. Download and extract the [MTK6589 Auto Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2107959&d=1373523917) folder.
4. Connect your phone to PC visa USB.
5. Run run.bat from the extracted MTK6589 Auto Root folder.
6. Press any key and wait while it roots your phone.
7. After finished, now reboot.
8. You’re rooted. Verify root with [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck), or run any app you know requires root and you should see a root permissions request.

Happy Flashing!!!

*Alternate method: Install and run through [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2784451&d=1402084843), this will temporarily root your phone.*

[Link to original post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2359221)